# MySQL function that returns a recordset in XML

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, function

I need to create a MySQL function that given a query string, a container name and a node name returns me a record in XML format as shown below.

As example, for this input:

```
Query string: "SELECT a, b, c FROM Table"
Container name: "orders"
Node name: "order"
```

The MySQL function has to return:

```
<orders>
     <order>
         <a>column content</a>
         <b>column content</b>
         <c>column content</c>
     </order>
     <order>
         <a>column content</a>
         <b>column content</b>
         <c>column content</c>
     </order>
</orders>
```

What is the easiest way to do it?

I've seen the use of "--xml" attribute attached to the mysql command and the outout that it produces would also be right to my need but is there a way to use it inside a MySQL function as in my case?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You will have to build a stored procedure to handle that given parameters. And then that proc would have to be run at command line which is the only place I know that MySQL returns an XML formatted resultset.

Comment: You could concatenate strings (i.e. opening and closing tags) as part of your query. That would work (I'm doing something similar when I need to return a JSON).